# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Inserting value from datetimepicker

Tags: c#, sql

I have this syntax on my program:

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand();
cmdInsert.Connection = con;
cmdInsert.CommandText =
"INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (@Firstname, @LastName, @Birthdate)";
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstname.Text;
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text;
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@BIrthdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpBirthdate.Value;
```

Whenever this code is executed, I get the error

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string"

I'm guessing that the problem roots from "dtpBirthdate.Value" syntax. I tried looking for a correct format for this part of the syntax but I never got lucky.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

I also changed `dtpBirthdate.Value` to `DBNull.Value` and it produces the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Date property of the returned DateTime:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.Date
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. What's wrong with my code is the sequence of the parameter variables in my insert statement. It should match the sequence of the columns in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DateTime.Parse(dtpBirthdate.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@BIrthdate", SqlDbType.String).Value = dtpBirthdate.Value;
```

Comment: Please add some description of what exactly your code does. It helps people to understand your solution better.

Comment: I meant please edit your answer and add your description. Moreover, add description and not yet more confusing code.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@BIrthdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  
                 dtpBirthdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```